# Using mysql to track "tip trails" from source user

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

I am working on a content aggregating tool idea, whose main feature will be the ability of the client to follow "tip trails" outward from the user to find new content that's likely to be valued by the user. These tips will represent voluntary Bitcoin tips, potentially miniscule.

Currently, the tips are stored in a table that tracks "from", "to", and "value". Here is an example of what I'd like to have happen, whether completely with mysql or by using a script that incorporates mysql. I've included a chart for reference:

```
                    feed makeup from
feed makeup from    final iteration
first iteration|             |
               |             |
     My tips   | pool 1 tips |
  -----------------------------
   |  me to A  |  A to A.a   | 60% of final feed from A.a
   |   (80%)   |   (75%)     |
   |           |             |
   |           |             |
   |           |             |
   |           |             |
   |           |- - - - - - ---
   |           |  A to A.b   | 20% of final feed from A.b
   |           |   (25%)     |
  --- - - - - -----------------
   |  me to B  |  B to B.a   | 20% of final feed from B.a
   |   (20%)   |   (100%)    |
  -----------------------------
```

The tool looks at everyone I've tipped, and finds that I've tipped both A and B. 80% of my tips have gone to A, and 20% to B. The tool generates a feed of content, heavily favoring content from A, as I've tipped 4X more to him than to B. This is the first iteration of the algorithm. I can then command the tool to perform the next iteration to generate a new feed, or add onto this feed. (Alternatively, mysql would perform N iterations all at once, but I don't believe this is possible with just pure SQL...)

To generate the next iteration of the feed, the tool looks at the tips sent by the pool generated by the first iteration, again weighted to favor A 80% and B 20% (regardless of whether, say, B has sent 1000 mBTC total and A has only tipped 2 mBTC total). It finds that 75% of A's tips have gone to some user A.a, and 25% have gone to another user A.b. We'll say that 100% of B's tips have gone toward yet another user, B.a.

The tool should then give me content with the following characteristics: A.a's content should fill 60% of my feed (80% * 75%); A.b's content should fill 20% of my feed (80% * 25%); and B.a's content should fill the remaining 20% of my feed (20% * 100%). Thus, all content has been weighted based primarily on my own tipping habits, then secondarily on the tipping habits of those who I've tipped, essentially creating a feed that predicts--based on people who I've already indicated I've valued--which content I'm likely to enjoy most.

I'm familiar with a lot of mysql's basic operation, and before I really started to look into a way to accomplish this, I just figured I could find some clever SQL to achieve what I'm trying to do--but now I'm less sure.

So, first of all, am I right in thinking that this kind of operation can't be achieved with mysql alone? If so, how might I write an algorithm that constructs the SQL needed for each iteration, then uses the result to construct the next query, and so on?

Any help here is immensely appreciated. If something doesn't make sense, I'll do my best to clarify. Thanks in advance for any direction you guys could provide!